How to stop Excel chart legend from overlapping the chart grid area?
How can I stop Excel chart legend from overlapping the chart grid area? No amount of clicking or dragging or digging through the menus solves this.
Excel for Mac

Could you please share us with a screenshot?
Do you mean this issue could not be adjust the Legend Position?
